# How to get explicit specified properties from xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, properties, grid, children

I have a loop with children of a grid. For every child, I want to know which properties have been specified explicitly in the XAML code. Do I have a chance to find out?

For example: I have a TextBox

```
<TextBox Height="150"/>
```

Only the property Height is given by XAML-Code. How I can find it out in the c# Code?
In other words, I don't want all of the properties of the TextBox, but only those who are specified in the XAML.

Comment: Its a bit treaky. You will need XAMLReader to do this. Take a look at this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xaml.xamlreader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: [Snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) knows at run-time if a property has its value set from Style/Template/Local/etc. without access to original XAML files. I'd dig a bit in snoop's code to see if I can find out how it's done. You're looking for properties that have their value set by `Local`.

Comment: Thx for your answers! I would like to not read the XAML-Code using a reader. Maybe Snoop used also a XmlReader... I dont know. But it seems not so easy to find it out.

Comment: XY Problem. What do you want this for?

Answer (score 3):

This was a challenging question, but luckily for you, I like a good challenge. So initially, I found the [`DependencyPropertyHelper.GetValueSource` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/En-Us/library/system.windows.dependencypropertyhelper.getvaluesource%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). This method takes a `DependencyObject` and a `DependencyProperty` and returns a `ValueSource struct`:

```
ValueSource valueSource = DependencyPropertyHelper.GetValueSource(SomeTextBlock, 
    TextBlock.TextWrappingProperty);
```

The `ValueSource struct` has a `BaseValueSource enum` property which has the following members:

[image]

These values relate to the list of `DependencyProperty` precedences and specify the different ways that a `DependencyProperty` value can be changed. A `BaseValueSource enum` instance value of `Local` means that the property was set locally using the `SetValue` method... this *will* also include instances where a property was set in code using the `SetValue` method. The Framework uses this method to set values from XAML markup.

The only problem was that we'd now have to find a collection of all of the `DependencyProperty`s of a particular `DependencyObject` so that we could call the above method on each to see if it was set by the `SetValue` method. I was hoping that Microsoft would have given us something to do this for us, but it appears not.

After a quick search, I found a way to do this using `Reflection` in the [List properties of a DependencyObject?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7570547/list-properties-of-a-dependencyobject) post here on StackOverflow. However, I kept looking and then came across a better method... a *much* better method. I found it in the [Getting list of all dependency/attached properties of an Object](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/580234cb-e870-4af1-9a91-3e3ba118c89c/getting-list-of-all-dependencyattached-properties-of-an-object?forum=wpf) question on the Visual Studio Forum.

If you look down that page at the answer from Zhou Yong, you can find a `DependencyPropertyHelper` class that he created. At first I thought 'let me just run this `DependencyPropertyHelper.GetValueSource` method to see what I get' and was expecting a long list of all of the `DependencyProperty`s of the `TextBlock`.

However, it turns out that what comes out of this method is exactly what you're after. It only returns the properties that *have actually been set in XAML*. In his code, I see a `MarkupObject`, a `MarkupProperty` and a `MarkupWriter`. I've not used these before, but it seems that this is actually looking at the XAML defined for the `TextBlock`. So in helping you, I've actually learned some new things too... +1 good question.

Bearing that in mind, I believe that you can ignore the earlier part of my answer regarding the `ValueSource struct` and just use that method. Let me know If you need any more help.

Answer (score 0):

You could inherit the TextBox in your own code. The PropertyChanged could then be overriden and you would receive any properties changing.

```
public class MyTextBox : TextBox
{
    public MyTextBox()
    {
    }

    protected override void OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Property changed: {0} {1}", e.Property.Name, e.NewValue));

        base.OnPropertyChanged(e);
    }
}

<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <local:MyTextBox x:Name="TB" Height="150"></local:MyTextBox>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

Unfortunatly you will also receive properties changed by styles

Here's the result of the code above

Property changed: UndoManagerInstance MS.Internal.Documents.UndoManager

Property changed: Instance System.Windows.Documents.TextEditor

Property changed: XmlnsDictionary System.Windows.Markup.XmlnsDictionary

Property changed: IWindowService WpfApplication1.MainWindow

Property changed: Name TB

Property changed: Height 150

Property changed: Background #FFFFFFFF

Property changed: BorderBrush #FFABADB3

Property changed: Foreground #FF000000

Property changed: BorderThickness 1,1,1,1

Property changed: TabNavigation None

Property changed: FocusVisualStyle

Property changed: AllowDrop True

Property changed: PanningMode VerticalFirst

Property changed: IsFlicksEnabled False

Property changed: Template System.Windows.Controls.ControlTemplate

Property changed: XmlNamespaceMaps System.Collections.Hashtable

Property changed: XmlnsDictionary System.Windows.Markup.XmlnsDictionary

Property changed: XmlNamespaceMaps System.Collections.Hashtable

Property changed: IsVisible True

Property changed: ActualWidth 509

Property changed: ActualHeight 150

Property changed: PageHeight 148

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/580234cb-e870-4af1-9a91-3e3ba118c89c/getting-list-of-all-dependencyattached-properties-of-an-object?forum=wpf) provided provided in Sheridan's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20141924/1988326), here is the very small code snippet required to get all the properties set on an element in XAML:

```cs
MarkupWriter.GetMarkupObjectFor(element).Properties
```